# Rails - move logic from each loop in view to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models - book.rb -

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
end
```

and user.rb -

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :books
end
```

books_controller.rb includes

```
def index
    @books = Book.all
end
```

And in /books/index.html.erb I have

```
<%= @books.each do |books| %>
  <%= book.title %>
  <%= User.find(book.user_id).name %>
 .....
```

This all works fine - but should I have more of that logic in the controller? And if so, how do I pass the book id from the block into the controller in order to pass back the user name?

Comment: You've missed `|` in  `<%= @books.each do |books %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to do so. Since you already have the `belongs_to` relation you can write your view as:

```
<%= @books.each do |books %>
  <%= book.title %>
  <%= book.user.name %>
 .....
```

Answer (score 0):

An even faster way to do this is:

```
def index
  @books = Book.includes(:user)
end
```

This will execute 2 SQL queries, one to get all the Books and one to get all associated Users. This is much cheaper in terms of number of queries, because if you have 10 Books you'd have to do 11 queries if you just use `Book.all` (one to get all the Books and one for each Book to get its User).

The view can stay the same:

```
<%= @books.each do |book| %>
  <%= book.title %>
  <%= book.user.name %>
  .....
```